# JetBrains CLion giving false positives in no_std nightly Rust, saying builtin types aren't `Sized`

Tags: macos, rust, clion, jetbrains-ide, rust-clippy

I am part of a project writing a kernel and OS in Rust. I am getting many false positives from the external linter (Clippy), such as:

> The size for values of type `&str` cannot be known at compilation time
> The size for values of type `core::str::Utf8Error` cannot be known at compilation time

etc.

I tried running Clippy in Terminal, and I just got other random warnings in my code (correctly).

Expected behavior: No incorrect errors
Received behavior: Incorrect errors

Comment: That doesn't sound like a linting error, that sounds like a compiler error. Have you run `cargo check`? What errors does that throw?

Comment: @isaactfa That also throws no errors. It's just when JetBrains parses the clippy external linter (fine with cargo check) stuff that it gets these weird errors. It also compiles just fine.

Comment: Well that is strange. Maybe the clippy and cargo versions went out of sync but I don't know how CLion those dependencies.

Comment: @isaactfa I thought that too, but I'm having this issue on two separate MacBooks.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that has this issue? A way to download your project where you encounter this issue (if it is open source) would be helpful in assisting you.